# AD authentication with Active Directory using Apache for Subversion

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, svn

Is there a Ubuntu package that includes auth_ldap for apache2?

- I don't see one...
- Google isn't helping me with this one
- `apt-cache show libapache2-webauth` doesn't show me if it's in there ... There a better command for this?

**Update:**
Actually  this looks pretty old, any one know if it is current and just hasn't needed an update?  What do you use to authenticate svn via Apache with AD?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
tuaca dpashley% dpkg -L apache2.2-common | grep ldap
/etc/apache2/mods-available/ldap.load
/etc/apache2/mods-available/authnz_ldap.load
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ldap.so
```

It's built into apache 2.2 and is called authnz-ldap.

Answer (score 1):

Apache+LDAP/AD is quite common for SVN authentication. If you want to add some more interest, and your clients support it, use Kerberos Binding/Authentication for users.